# RDP multiple session by one user at the same time

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

finally, I find a solution for multiple remote connections at the same time, by following steps on a tutorial: [How Many Users Can Remote Desktop 2012?](https://operavps.com/how-many-users-can-remote-desktop-2012/)

All is well now, but a user can login to multiple sessions at the same time too! how can I restrict them to one?

Comment: You actively chose to allow it. So just undo that change?

Comment: I see you proposed a very significant edit to another answer. We encourage people to answer their own questions if they've found the answers, and your edit really changed the entire answer. I would recommend that, rather than editing the answer as you did, you simply post that information as an answer, and then mark it as such, so you'll get the points for getting a good answer, and others in the future will be able to see how you solved your specific problem and follow those steps to solve their own.

Answer (score 0):

You just wanted to enable multiple session and then you want to disable it?
anyways:

Click Start > Administrative Tools > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration. Then you have to go to "General", double click "Restrict each user to a single session" and select "Restrict each user to a single session".